# How do I programmatically close an alert dailog on event occurrance

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do I programmatically close an alert dailog if specific event has occurred...for example...alert dailog must close itself when a new message is received... Please help

Comment: please post code. show us your dialog, as well as the code for getting a new message

Answer (score 2):

All Dialogs will implement `dismiss()` and `cancel()` via the [`DialogInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html).

> I would strongly suggest reading the [Official Android Developers guide on Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for more information and best practices.

Comment: Okey,how do I code so that dailog automatically get dismissed on new message arrival?